# How to group-by and simultaneously add up time values in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have following Source Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 0.0, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.2", "UDP" , 64], 
                                      [2, 0.2, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.3", "UDP" , 64],
                                      [3, 0.8, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.4", "UDP" , 64],
                                      [4, 1.01, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.2", "UDP" , 64],
                                     [5, 1.23, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.3", "UDP" , 64],
                                     [6, 1.44, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.4", "UDP" , 64],
                                     [7, 1.90, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.2", "UDP" , 64],
                                     [8, 2.05, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.3", "UDP" , 64],
                                     [9, 2.3, "192.168.1.1" ,"192.168.1.4", "UDP" , 64]]),
                            columns=['No.', 'Time','Source', 'Destination', 'Protocol', 'Length'],
                            index =['0', '1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8'])
```

The output is that:

```
    No. Time    Source      Destination Protocol    Length
0   1   0.0     192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 UDP           64
1   2   0.2     192.168.1.1 192.168.1.3 UDP           64
2   3   0.8     192.168.1.1 192.168.1.4 UDP           64
3   4   1.01    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 UDP           64
4   5   1.23    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.3 UDP           64
5   6   1.44    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.4 UDP           64
6   7   1.9     192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 UDP           64
7   8   2.05    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.3 UDP           64
8   9   2.3     192.168.1.1 192.168.1.4 UDP           64
```

Now i want to group-by a new Column that sums up the "Time" column and groups it every second. This is the Output i want to achieve:

```
              Number of Frames  Cumulative_Length 
First_Second         3                  192
Second_Second        4                  256
Third_Second         2                  128
```

The number of Frames are the number of rows for each second.
The cumulative length is the sum of the "Length"-column for every second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
new_df = ( df.groupby(np.floor(df.Time))
             .Length
             .agg(Number_of_Frames='size',
                  Cumulative_Length='sum') )
```

**Output**

```
      Number_of_Frames  Cumulative_Length
Time                                     
0.0                  3                192
1.0                  4                256
2.0                  2                128
```

---

**Changing the index**

```
#pip install inflect
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()
new_df.index= [p.ordinal(i)+'_Second' for i in range(1,len(new_df)+1)]
print(new_df)
            Number_of_Frames  Cumulative_Length
1st_Second                 3                192
2nd_Second                 4                256
3rd_Second                 2                128
```